# ElasticBeanstalk MultiContainer docker with nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two applications that handle different, but related functionality. I would like to deploy them as a single entity on a single host:port.

My plan is to use elasticbeanstalk's multicontainer docker platform. Each application would be a container.

How can I tie them together? Is it possible to install and configure nginx on the eb host?

Comment: I've run NGINX as a antoher container with port 80 binded to host. On DockerHub you should find easliy nginx image. I'm not sure how your containers should communicate with each other, but I think that maybe host's sockets would be fine. Each container creates sockets and store them in volume accessible by othe container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define all containers  that comprise your application (together with nginx container) in `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/conf.d"
      }
    }  
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "first-app",
      "image": "FIRST_APP_IMAGE_NAME:FIRST_APP_TAG",
      "environment": [],
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8081,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "secondapp",
      "image": "SECOND_APP_IMAGE_NAME:SECOND_APP_TAG",
      "environment": [],
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 200,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8082,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ]
    }
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "firstapp", "secondapp"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
          "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now as we linked app containers to nginx container we can refer to them using their names as hostnames.

And then you need to deploy Dockerrun.aws.json zipped together with nginx config `conf.d/default.conf` file (put into `conf.d` folder) in which you need to specify

```
location /firstapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://firstapp;
}

location /secondapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://secondapp;
}
```

Please also refer to AWS example of nginx proxy before php application.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html

Comment: the nginx location block wont work ,try it youll see.